# defaultValue doesn't change... dropdown react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a dropdown that get it's option from a fetch, and when I select and option another fetch is requested to save that into the DB, and then it return that into the state so the selected value is now in the state.
BUT!
my dropdown doesn't update the selected value, even though it updates correctly in the DB.

the dropdown:

```
<Form.Field className="dropdown">
   <label>{answer.answerText}</label>
   <Dropdown  
    key={ answer.name } 
    value={answer.value <!--THIS IS UPDATED AFTER SELECTION, BUT DOESN'T SHOW -->} 
    style={{paddingLeft: pad}} 
    onChange={(e) => this.blurHandler(e.target.textContent,answer)}  
    name={ answer.name } 
    disabled={answer.settings.disabled} 
    options={answer.dropdownOptions}
   />
</Form.Field>
```

The method that gets called.

```
blurHandler(e,answer) {
    var answerValue = e;
    var projectId = this.props.projectId;
    this.props.updateAnswer('/api/update-answer', 
      answer.questionId,
      projectId,
      answer._id, 
      answerValue, 
      answer.settings.answerType
      );
}
```

what updateAnswer does is just a fetch to save the value to the projects answer in the DB.

Comment: can you also include the selection updation method

Comment: What is that? How does that look?

Comment: are you using redux?Is the answers object a state ?

Comment: Yeah I'm using redux and the answer object is a state that has been passed down from a parent

Comment: i think the problem is, redux store may not be updating after the api being called so the state does not change.can you put your code in jsfiddle or codesandbox

Comment: It's alot of code, and it needs a DB to function properly, since the whole website is building itself from data from the database, but I checked and the state does update, but the Dropdown always shows option1 (there is 2 options, option 1 and option 2), and that doesn't change no matter what, but everything else works correctly

Comment: Please include more code,as how states are set when the api call is success.So that we can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176405/discussion-between-harikrishnan-and-charlie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title says `defaultValue` but you do not use that prop anywhere in your `Dropdown` component. When you are defining a `value` in your `Dropdown` component, or on any SUIR component, that means you must control all other input interactions yourself and you lose any of the out of the box state controls that come with SUIR components. There are definitely cases where you might want this.

I'd recommend changing your `value` prop to a `defaultValue` prop on your `Dropdown` and that should give you what you're expecting. The `Dropdown` will only initialize itself with that value but it will change in the UI the way you are expecting.